# images not displayed in xib and in simulator while using xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have updated some functionality in an old app that was built on ios4 and there was no update after that. When I tried to upload binary on app store I was asked to build binary with xcode5. I setup xcode5 and import code there but most of the images in UIImageView are not displayed in xib as well as in simulator. I have put 2x images but no result.
Please suggest me if some other settings to be done or need to create some other size images.

Comment: in UiimageView you adding image programatically or just dragging image to UiimageView??

Comment: I am adding images in xib not programatically.

Comment: Xib not work properly when your create the xib in xcode4 and use it in xcode5

Comment: did you get warning messages

Comment: what is your image name text using

Comment: post your relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Interface builder]Check you xib in both Xcode 5 and 4 .Actually when you will switch from xcode 4 xib to Xcode 5 xib then it changes its coordinates automatically . So you have to set its frame in your class instead of xib. I have faced the same problem now it is resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot Manish, this was the problem. frame was reset to 0,490,0,0. I set correct coordinate and it works.
I am updating it in xcode5 xib, is it enough or need to update from code?

Comment: there is one problem image is displayed in xib but still not displayed in simulator.

Comment: @kapil : Do one thing from the right side in your xcode , in interface builder change you Xib to check you frame in both Xcode 5 and 4 option is view as, for reference you have to check screenshot attached in answer. But if you will set frame in class.No need to taking care about Xib.

Comment: @kapil: if you find the solution correct marked this answer as answered . So other one's will not use there precious time. And others can also take help from it. Marked it as correct so it will show green colour tick icon.